# Error while compilation of std::map with boost::shared_ptr

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, stdmap

I am trying to compile my code in vs2005.
I am using std::map and boost::shared_ptr (v1.47.0)
My code looks something like this

```
struct B {
    int a;
}
typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> K;

std::map<const std::string, K > mymap;

//some code

std::map<const std::string, K >::iterator it;
for (it = mymap.begin(); it < mymap.end(); it++ )
{
     //do something
}
```

The compiler is giving an error at the for statement.
The following is the error

error C2784: 'bool boost::operator <(const boost::intrusive_ptr &,const boost::intrusive_ptr &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const boost::intrusive_ptr &' from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator for the checking against `mymap.end()`. Change the loop to

```
for (it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++ )
```